# The blocked conversion pipe

Tags: conversion, magento-enterprise, ee-1.11

We host a shop with around 100 orders per day. In the day time there are around 10 orders per hour.
Some times, for an hour there is no order at all.

The shop owner, who monitors the current conversions, then makes a test order (which works fine). And right after that the orders start to flow in again.

This seems to be not linked to a specific time of the day. And the unique visitors do not drop - only the conversion rate.

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Any possibility that it's just pure coincidence?

Comment: @Kenny: That's what I also said - but the customer keeps insisting and this phenomena happens at least once in a week.

Comment: If you are using Google Analytics you should be able to get more info from there. (Especially if you have funnels setup) ;)

Comment: I would also recommend looking at Google Analytics, but I would also say that if you see that traffic dropping out during the order process, check the server logs for errors which could be killing the orders.

Comment: It could also be a caching related issue...

Answer (score 5):

Of course there is no chance to diagnose this problem here. The only thing that can give you a hint is analyzing if there's anything peculiar in those "pushing" orders: user agent, products in cart, shipping/payment method, way of checkung out (guest/registration/logged in) etc.

Also as Kenny advised GA funnels will visualise the orders flow.

Plan 9: Suggest your client to find a good doctor.

Comment: I forwarded your suggestion to the client and he fired me. *just kidding*

Comment: look positive. you got rid of sick client :-)